# Laravel with PostgreSQL and Postgis point

Tags: laravel, postgresql, geolocation, postgis

I develop an application which allows to post(show) a list of restaurants according to the location(localization) of the user.

For that purpose, I have a base(basis) of datum containing bars with their latitudes-longitudes.

My database is under postgresql and I would like to use, all my back-service(back-office) is under Laravel. At present to add a `POINT`, I make: `ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;(110 30)')`, but on Laravel, the request SQL ( db:seed ) includes the ST_ guillement enter.

`DB::table('establishments')->insert(['location' =>ST_GeogFromText(\'SRID=4326;POINT(-110 30)\'),]),` but `ST_GeogFromText` is not a fonction -- 
The error message:

> parse error - invalid geometry HINT: "ST"

How may I make to manage PostgreSQL-Postgis and Laravel?

Comment: Have you tried `ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(110 30)');`?

Comment: I didn't quite get the issue here. Are you unable to add points to your db? If so, can you elaborate a bit more on the procedure and the error message?

Comment: I try to add an entity in my db with Laravel seeding, so i make DB::table('establishments')->insert(['location' => ST_GeogFromText(\'SRID=4326;POINT(-110 30)\'),]), but ST_GeogFromText is not a fonction -- The error message are : parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "ST"

Comment: Just to make it clearer: you're sure that the PostGIS extension is installed in your database, right?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, but i think it is laravel the problem

Answer (score 1):

`ST_GeogFromText` is a PostGIS function not a PHP/Laravel function, and you cannot wrap it in quotes (i.e. `""`), as Laravel will then consider it a string.

Instead, pass a **raw** query expression like below:

```php
DB::table('establishments')->insert([
    'location' => DB::raw("ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-110 30)')"),
    // your other columns & values
]);
```